# Não consigo entrar no foreach de uma blade no laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, foreach, view, laravel-blade

Estou com um pequeno problema que ainda não consegui descobrir como resolver, tenho uma `View` e não consigo entrar no `foreach` desta mesma, segue a `View`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}        

    <!--{{ dd($impressora) }}-->
    @foreach($impressora as $sheets)
        {{ dd('teste') }}
        <!--{{ dd($sheets) }}-->
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="setor">Setor*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o setor..." required="required" name="setor" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->setor }}" id="setor">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="marca">Marca*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a marca..." required="required" name="marca" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->marca }}" id="marca">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="modelo">Modelo*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o modelo..." required="required" name="modelo" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->modelo }}" id="modelo">
            </div>     
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o tipo do tonner..." required="required" name="tipo" type="text" value="Tinta" id="tipo">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tonner">Tonner*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o modelo do tonner..." required="required" name="tonner" type="text" value="Tinta" id="tonner">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="setor">Setor*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o setor..." required="required" name="setor" type="text" value="T.I." id="setor">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="local">Local*:</label>
                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="local" name="local">
                    <option value="MG0" selected="selected">Fábrica Minas</option>
                    <option value="SP0">Loja SP Mendes Júnior</option>
                    <option value="SP1">Loja SP Xavantes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="datacompra">Data da Compra*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" required="required" name="datacompra" type="date" value="2015-08-05" id="datacompra">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="ativo">Em Uso*:</label>
                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="ativo" name="ativo">
                    <option value="S" selected="selected">Sim</option>
                    <option      value="N">Não</option>
                    <option value="0">Descartado</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Esse é o controller:

```
public function tonerSheets($id)
{        
    $impressora  = $this->TiImpressoraM->find($id);                
    return view('portal.ti.impressoras.TiImpressorasToner', compact('impressora'));
}
```

Antes do `foreach` corre tudo normal, inclusive no teste feito mas não entra no `foreach` por nada nesse mundo, o que será que eu fiz errado?

***PS:*** Eu pesquisei em um monte de lugares inclusive aqui no site e não consegui encontrar nada nesse sentido, vi muitos problemas de `foreach` mas nenhum parecido com esse, se já houver algo com a mesma ideia que possa ajudar poderiam por favor me direcionar?

Resultado do Dump antes do `foreach`:

> TiImpressora {#898 ▼
>     #fillable: array:9 [▼
>       0 => "patrimonio"
>       1 => "ip"
>       2 => "marca"
>       3 => "modelo"
>       4 => "tonner"
>       5 => "setor"
>       6 => "datacompra"
>       7 => "local"
>       8 => "ativo"
>     ]
>     #connection: "mysql"
>     #table: null
>     #primaryKey: "id"
>     #keyType: "int"
>     +incrementing: true
>     #with: []
>     #withCount: []
>     #perPage: 15
>     +exists: true
>     +wasRecentlyCreated: false
>     #attributes: array:12 [▼
>       "id" => 1
>       "patrimonio" => 35
>       "ip" => ""
>       "marca" => "Brohter"
>       "modelo" => "DCP-J125"
>       "tonner" => "Tinta"
>       "setor" => "T.I."
>       "datacompra" => "2015-08-05"
>       "local" => "MG0"
>       "ativo" => "S"
>       "created_at" => null
>       "updated_at" => "2018-04-13 19:14:06"
>     ]
>     #original: array:12 [▼
>       "id" => 1
>       "patrimonio" => 35
>       "ip" => ""
>       "marca" => "Brohter"
>       "modelo" => "DCP-J125"
>       "tonner" => "Tinta"
>       "setor" => "T.I."
>       "datacompra" => "2015-08-05"
>       "local" => "MG0"
>       "ativo" => "S"
>       "created_at" => null
>       "updated_at" => "2018-04-13 19:14:06"
>     ]
>     #casts: []
>     #dates: []
>     #dateFormat: null
>     #appends: []
>     #events: []
>     #observables: []
>     #relations: []
>     #touches: []
>     +timestamps: true
>     #hidden: []
>     #visible: []
>     #guarded: array:1 [▼
>       0 => "*"
>     ]
>   }

Não sei se é assim que deveria formatar...

Comment: $impressora não é uma lista! Por isso não funciona

Comment: Oi @Virgilio Novic, obrigado por responder, mas eu ainda fiquei em dúvida, por lista você quer dizer array certo? Se for o caso, no teste que eu fiz, fora do foreach ele me retorna o array como deveria mas, dentro do foreach não, aliás, nem entra no foreach.
Se for o caso de $impressora não ser uma lista, onde estou errando?

Comment: ` $impressora  = $this->TiImpressoraM->find($id);` nessa linha retornar uma impressora ou `null`, ai eu fiquei na duvida você quer retornar somente uma ou uma lista de impressoras?

Comment: Me retorna o array com as informações de uma impressora específica, como eu esperava.

Comment: Então, esse comando retorna uma impressora então é isso que você quer testar se a impressora retornou valores em objeto ou array???

Comment: O que eu preciso é do array mesmo, dentro do foreach, eu preciso de alguns volores dentro do array para passá-los para a view e eventualmente, também usar esse valores para uma outra operação.

Comment: `$impressora  = $this->TiImpressoraM->all()` isso te retorno o coleção (ou `array`) do outro jeito uma impressora! qual dos dois ...?

Comment: Desculpe @Virgilio Novic, não entendi a pergunta...

Comment: Vamos tentar entender: o comando que você deu no `controller` retorna um instância daquela classe TiImpressoraM, ai você foi na `View` é quer imprimir a coleção dessa classe, isso não vai funcionar porque $impressora é uma impressora e não é uma coleção de impressora. Se o comando estiver certo no `controller` o `foreach` está errado na `View`? Eu já te perguntei se é uma impressora o resultado mesmo se for já te falo o que deve fazer!

Comment: Desculpe @Virgilio Novic, já deve ter percebido que sou bem novo em PHP e Laravel, de qualquer forma, eu postei o resultado do Dump antes do foreach na pergunta original, se ajudar...

Comment: Sem problemas você quer um resultado somente olha a resposta

Comment: Uma pergunta, porque você está tentando iterar um Model e ainda está usando o nome `$sheets`? Será que você não quer pegar um relacionamento desse Model? Tipo `$impressora->sheets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está retornando uma coleção, você está retornando um dado simples, retire o `foreach` e coloque um `if`, exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}        
    @if(isset($impressora))            
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="setor">Setor*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o setor..." required="required" name="setor" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->setor }}" id="setor">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="marca">Marca*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a marca..." required="required" name="marca" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->marca }}" id="marca">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="modelo">Modelo*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o modelo..." required="required" name="modelo" type="text" value="{{ $sheets->modelo }}" id="modelo">
            </div>     
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o tipo do tonner..." required="required" name="tipo" type="text" value="Tinta" id="tipo">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tonner">Tonner*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o modelo do tonner..." required="required" name="tonner" type="text" value="Tinta" id="tonner">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="setor">Setor*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o setor..." required="required" name="setor" type="text" value="T.I." id="setor">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="local">Local*:</label>
                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="local" name="local">
                    <option value="MG0" selected="selected">Fábrica Minas</option>
                    <option value="SP0">Loja SP Mendes Júnior</option>
                    <option value="SP1">Loja SP Xavantes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="datacompra">Data da Compra*:</label>
                <input class="form-control" required="required" name="datacompra" type="date" value="2015-08-05" id="datacompra">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="ativo">Em Uso*:</label>
                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="ativo" name="ativo">
                    <option value="S" selected="selected">Sim</option>
                    <option   value="N">Não</option>
                    <option value="0">Descartado</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    @end
</div>
```

Comment: Eu tentei trocando o `foreach` por `if`, mas continua do mesmo jeito, não entra no bloco do `if`...

Comment: @GabrielSassaki rapaz é pra funcionar!

Comment: Estranho né, eu dei um Dump com o comando `{{ dd($impressora) }}` antes do `if` e depois do `if`, o de antes funcionou, o de depois não...

Comment: Lá embaixo tem um `@endforeach`, coloque somente `@end`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic faltou trocar `$sheets` por `$impressora` no HTML dentro do `if`. Acho que por isso o teu exemplo não funcionou pra ele.

Comment: Editei a resposta novamente @GabrielSassaki

Comment: Editei a resposta @fernandosavio é muito html a gente acaba se perdendo

Comment: Eu troquei sim, `@endforeach` por `@endif` e alterei tudo que precisa dentro do bloco `if`...

Comment: Eu comentei porque pode ser por isso que tu solução não funcionou pra ele.. Se ele só copiou e colocou vai dar erro

Comment: @GabrielSassaki não funcionou?

Comment: Entendi, não funcionou, aconteceu o mesmo que o `foreach`...

Comment: Acho eu que você ta perdidaço @GabrielSassaki só pode, porque é pra funcionar!

Comment: Verdade mesmo, é pra funcionar mas por algum motivo qualquer não está indo, amanhã eu vou rever tudo que for possível e aviso vocês, de repente é algma coisa bem besta... Mas vlw mesmo assim...